# Android: how to deal with devices with unfortunate dpi classification?

Tags: android

My application has a toolbar with ImageButtons that I use as application buttons.  I specify the layout_width and layout_height of the buttons as 12mm. (12mm * 160dpi) / (25.4 mm/in ) = 75.9pix, on a 160dpi device.  Similarly, it will be 113.4pix on a 240dpi device.  So, I would be inclined to make my mdpi drawables about 60x60 and my hdpi drawables about 90x90 (to allow for some margins and such).

However, I run into an issue on devices like my Samsung Galaxy Tab.  Which, unfortunately, is classified as hdpi despite being only 170dpi.  At 170dpi, 12 mm = 80.3pix.  But, because it is hdpi, it will use the 90x90 icon, which is far too big.

My inclination is forgo the ldpi/mdpi/hdpi framework, and just package icons at 30x30, 40x40, 50x50... 100x100.  And, in code, choose which one to use based on the stated dpi on the device (which is also inaccurate, but far less so).  However, this seems hard to maintain and just generally inefficient.

Any advice on how to handle this situation?

Comment: you might find [this thread from the mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg134533.html) very interesting (although not answering your question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the absolute size units like mm and in.  With the way current devices are, they can't be relied on.  Only use px and dp.

Comment: I played with that, but it doesn't seem to help anything.  The idea behind the 12mm is for the button to always be the size of a fingertip (mine is 12 mm).  This can't be accomplished at all if I use dp.  For example if I use something like 60dp, it will use 60 pixels on a 160dpi device, which will render as 9.525mm; and on the 170dpi Samsung Tab device it will use 90pix, which will render as 13.44mm.  The 9.525mm is unusably small on the 160dpi device, and 13.44mm is noticeably too large on the Galaxy tab.  Dpis would work if they were a precise ratio, on the tab it should be 170/160, not 1.5

Comment: Here it sounds like Samsung basically decided that they want things to look very large on the tab. So just go with it, it's how other apps work and look and it was a design decision made by Samsung. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/screen-geometry-fun.html

Comment: Ignore the Galaxy Tab; it uses an unusually high density for its screen, which was a compromise for before Android 3.0 when apps would not do much with the extra space.  Instead, it has a fair amount of extra space for the UI, but not as much as you expect because it is using a higher density and thus scaling the UI.

Comment: Besides that, just give up on trying to make your buttons some exact size.  You will just drive yourself crazy.  That's not how apps work on Android -- what you are supposed to do is scale the UI based on the density, which is quantized into a small set of buckets.  Different devices will have different screen dpis but map to the same bucket; thus the overall UI size will vary slightly between these devices but all apps use the density and so have a consistent result on a particular device and the manufacturer picks the density bucket for the experience they want on their product.